# Set band fill in script in Fast Report 5 VCL

Tags: delphi, fastreport

Is it possible to set the band fill in a BeforePrint event?  I tried the following but get the error "Could not convert variant of type (null) int type (integer)":

```
procedure MasterData1OnBeforePrint(Sender: TfrxComponent);
begin
  if <USERS."DELETED"> = 1 then
    MasterData1.Fill.BackColor := cl3dLight; // 'cl3dLight' does not work either.
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

TfrxBrushFill(MasterData1.Fill).BackColor := cl3dLight;

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just adding a rectangular TfrxShapeView object and sizing it to the band.  I then make it visible or invisible as required.

I would still like to know why you can't adjust the fill of the band itself in script though.